# Date Picker(Calendar icon) for SSRS parameter are not displayed in Microsoft Edge

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

The web application that i am working on now able to display the SSRS Report in Internet Explorer11.

Problem: When I try to run the web application in Edge Browser, the calendar icon disappears on Edge browser. I did some research and found out that Microsoft Edge did not support calendar control in SSRS till SSRS-2014. Besides I tried to change the meta tag in reportviewer.aspx to make it compatible with Edge browser. Unfortunately, I cannot apply this method as it will affect other system report that using another browser (server-side).

Add on: The web application need to launch in Microsoft Edge based on the requirements.

Anyone have any idea/alternative to solve this issues.

Thanks, 
Taeron

Answer (score 0):

From your tag, I gather that you are using SSRS 2008. Calender's do no render in Edge as it is HTML 5 (if I'm not wrong!). You either need to use an older version of Internet Explorer.. or upgrade your SSRS instance to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, means i need to use higher version of the SSRS that compatible with Edge browser right?

Comment: @Taeron Yes.. that is correct. Upgrade to SSRS 2016 and above should do the trick. I use SSRS 2016 and can vouch that it works fine on Edge.